# Sublime Text 3 - Lyte theme doesn't affect sidebar / tab view

Tags: themes, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The Lyte theme should not only change the way the code looks but the appearance of the sidebar and the tab view as well according to this [readme](https://github.com/lytedev/lyte-theme/blob/master/README.md). I installed it via Package Control, and it doesn't appear to be working for me:

[image: Lyte theme applies to code but not to sidebar nor to the tab view]

I restarted and reinstalled it several times, do I have to set a special config for this to work or something like that?

(I tried some other themes that should've changed the view of the sidebar and the tabs as well and they didn't work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have only changed the color_scheme, which can be done in the menu, you need to also change the theme in the settings file:

Add/edit this to your Preferences: Settings - User

```
{
    "theme": "Lyte-Dark.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Lyte/Lyte-Dark/Lyte-Dark.tmTheme",
}
```

docs: https://github.com/lytedev/lyte-theme/blob/master/README.md#usage